# add breaks to tm_bubbles/tm_symbol

Tags: r, break, tmap

I have the following map.

I would like to create breaks for the cumulated conflicts.

I wrote the following code but it does not work.

```
tm_shape(test) + 
  tm_polygons(col="vcidrought_type",
          pal =c("#BCE395","#21908CFF", "#3B528BFF", "#440154FF", "#000004FF"),
          levels = labels,
          title="Drought types") +
  tm_layout(main.title = "VCI drought type in Sub-Saharan Africa 1997-2010", 
            main.title.position = "center", frame= FALSE) +
  tm_shape(shp_union) +
  tm_symbols(col = "red", border.col = "black", size = "total_conflicts",
             breaks = c(-Inf, seq(1000, 4000, by = 1000), Inf),
             title.size = "Cumulated conflicts")
```

[image]

Comment: the documentation for `tm_symbols` doesn't specify acceptable ranges but the Inf may be causing issues.  Presumably there are no areas with <0 conflicts so the range could be `c(0,1000,2000,3000,4000,1E10)` or similar?

Comment: It does not work as well. It seems that any break specification would not work as in the 'col' it is not "total_conflicts". So, here the breaks are automatically determined.